# async/aiohttp помочь с решением ограничения Windows

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Я для парсинга использую aiohttp и async.
На windows имеется ограничение в 64 одновременных сокета.
Чтобы обойти это ограничение, посоветовали использовать ProactorEventLoop.

Я попробовал, но мне постоянно кидает, что я использую разные  event loop.

Помогите, как исправить мой код, чтобы обойти это ограничение

```
async def start_main(root_items):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        initial_future = loop.create_future()
        initial_future.set_result(root_items)
        await crawl(initial_future, pool)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(urls))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Использую Python 3.6.8
[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675410/python-asyncio-aiohttp-valueerror-too-many-file-descriptors-in-select-on-win)

Заменил loop в Main и стало кидать ошибки

```
Exception in callback _ProactorBaseWritePipeTransport._loop_writing(<_OverlappedF...hed result=31>)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBaseWritePipeTransport._loop_writing(<_OverlappedF...hed result=31>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 271, in _loop_writing
    assert f is self._write_fut
AssertionError
```

Comment: А сколько сокетов нужно? Мультипроцессингом можно насоздавать штук 64*63 без особых потерь

Comment: @eri, ну хотя бы 1000

Comment: ProcessPoolExecutor не пробовал?